# indicate a password for git pull in shell script, without ssh?

Tags: git, shell

I wrote a shell script to do project releasing with `Git`, in the shell script I first `cd` to the Git working copy and then do `git pull origin master`.
But it prompts me for password: `git@localhost's password:`, this's annoying, and I'm wondering if I can indicate the password for `git pull` in the script, like this:
`git pull origin master --password abcd123`
Any idea?

Comment: I want to indicate the password and not config ssh because I need to make this script executable from php pages.

Comment: I recall there was a program to enter passwords from within scripts. Can't recall how it's called though

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you tell me what that is when you recall. Why does not Git support --password argument or something alike, mysql and  mongodb client and many other tools support this.

Comment: Because git has not authentication of itself. But I know in recent versions of git there are some authentication helpers, but not sure what they exactly do.

Comment: @Ikke I found the program you mentioned, it's sshpass, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm fairly sure that was not the program I meant, but that could work too.

Comment: Note that you can use it with ssh keys even though the script would be executable from php pages.

Comment: The program I was talking about was called [expect](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally: Don't put passwords into scripts and especially don't supply them with command arguments because that means they are published via the `ps` command to anyone on the same computer.

The solution here is to use ssh and run an ssh agent. The agent loads your private key and supplies that to the shell script when it tries to connect to the remote side via SSH. That way, you only need to give your pass phrase to the agent.

This blog post should give you more details: [Password-less logins with OpenSSH](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)

If you're using Windows, [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) comes with the same functionality.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. This just says "Do it this way instead" best practices or not, you should answer the question. Some implementations of git (TFS) dosnt play nicely with scripts because you need to do things in windows. Any devops person will tell you for automating tasks you WANT passwords in source control (in a protected repo of course)

Comment: @CyberMen: Which is why I wrote "run an ssh agent". Load your keys (from whatever protected source) into the agent and you're set. If you have a version of Git which doesn't support scripting, you're using the wrong tool.