# Pass username password in git pull

Tags: git

I am trying to update my repository using

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

using a batch script on windows, but it asks for username and password, can't I pass them as arguments, something like

```
git pull --rebase origin master --username user1 --password pass1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [indicate a password for git pull in shell script, without ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597546/indicate-a-password-for-git-pull-in-shell-script-without-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a non-ssh based solution and

`git-credential-winstore` is exactly what I was looking for.

Download link

```
http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

You must verify keys. You must be able to connect ssh in git server with `ssh git@address` if you can't then verify keys.

Generate ssh keys for the current user and puts public key in git server.

Comment: This is quite unclear, but there is a good answer [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597546/indicate-a-password-for-git-pull-in-shell-script-without-ssh) which in turn points to [some documentation about passwordless authentication with ssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/152/Password-less_logins_with_OpenSSH)